# knockout data keep adding on the jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

I am having issue with knockout and jquery dialog. The thing is I am opening the dialog on hyperlink .The issue is every time I close and open the dialog, I am getting the duplication data. The data is being appended again and again whenever I close and open the dialog. I tried destroying the dialog on close of dialog but still the issue persists.

WHAT I AM DOING IN THE FOLLOWING CODE

1) I am opening a div with a dialog .In the open event of the dialog i am getting data from the server .

2) I am using knockout view model to store and persist the data.

WHAT IS THE ISSUE

I am getting the duplicate rows on each hyperlink click whenever i open and close the dialog.The issue will not happen on the first page load.The issue appears only on further clicking of hyperlink.

```
 <div id="divforjobactivity" class="hidden">
    <h5 class="title1" style="padding-left: 500px">
        Job Activity Form</h5>
    <table id="gvActivityForm" class="test">
        <thead>
        <tr> <td> <div id="divstatus"></div> </td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="thdata">
             Y1
            </th>
 <th class="thdata">
             Y2
            </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody data-bind="foreach: arraytoadd">

                    <tr>

                         <td data-bind="text: y1"></td>

                        <td data-bind="text: y2"></td>



    </table>



</div>
 $(document).on("click", "[id*=hypJobActivity]", function () {

      var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');  // gets closest parent tr element to the anchor element
      var x1 = $(".x1", $(this).closest("tr")).html()
      var $addJobActivityContainer = $("#divforjobactivity"); 
      TemplateFunction = function () {

        var self = this;
        self.y2 =ko.observable(0);
        self.y1 = ko.observable(0);        
    }
    // set the view model for 
      JobActivity = function () {

        var self = this;
        self.errors = ko.observableArray();
        self.arraytoadd = ko.observableArray();
        self.addevent = function () {

            self.arraytoadd.push(new TemplateFunction());
        }
    }      

    jobactivityVM = new JobActivity();
    ko.cleanNode($addJobActivityContainer[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(jobactivityVM, $addJobActivityContainer[0]);
    obj = {};        
    obj.x1 = x1;       
    $("#divforjobactivity").dialog({ height: 320,width: 1230,modal: true,

 open:function   (event,ui)         
            $.ajax({     //start ajax call for posting and getting the data back
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'PopupWebService.asmx/ReceiveandSendJobActivity',
                data: JSON.stringify({ item: obj }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {                      

                    for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {

                        var x = new TemplateFunction();
                        x.y1(response.d[i].Y1); 
                        x.y2=((response.d[i].Y2);                                       
                        jobactivityVM.arraytoadd.push(x);
                    }                  

                }, //end of sucess att

                close: function (event, ui) {

                    $("#divforjobactivity").dialog("destroy");
                    $("#divforjobactivity").remove();
                }, // end of close 

                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Unable to retrieve requested information " + errorThrown);

                }     //end of error

            }); //END OF DIALOG
```

Comment: Can you please post the HTML.  Also I can't seem to find the closing ")" for the $.ajax call in your sample above

Comment: Robert .I updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Robert Stanley and @James Thorpe ,thanks for your help . I tried your solutions @Robert ,I tried ist part of your solution and @james i tried your solution . The issue is i have to take the apply bindings off from the hyperlink click event .The multiple binding is causing an issue .

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

// I have changed the logic of placing the code from the click event to document ready becaaue my dom is not refreshed if i just open and close the dialog and i am using the appply binding on the click event.

{

```
 var $addJobActivityContainer = $("#divforjobactivity"); 
var $addJobActivityContainer = $("#divforjobactivity"); 
  TemplateFunction = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.y2 =ko.observable(0);
    self.y1 = ko.observable(0);        
}
// set the view model for 
  JobActivity = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.errors = ko.observableArray();
    self.arraytoadd = ko.observableArray();
    self.addevent = function () {

        self.arraytoadd.push(new TemplateFunction());
    }
}      

jobactivityVM = new JobActivity();
ko.cleanNode($addJobActivityContainer[0]);
ko.applyBindings(jobactivityVM, $addJobActivityContainer[0]);





$(document).on("click", "[id*=hypJobActivity]", function () {


  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');  // gets closest parent tr element to the anchor element
  var x1 = $(".x1", $(this).closest("tr")).html()

   obj = {};        
   obj.x1 = x1;    


$("#divforjobactivity").dialog({ height: 320,width: 1230,modal: true,
```

open:function   (event,ui)
            $.ajax({     //start ajax call for posting and getting the data back
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'PopupWebService.asmx/ReceiveandSendJobActivity',
                data: JSON.stringify({ item: obj }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

```
                for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {

                    var x = new TemplateFunction();
                    x.y1(response.d[i].Y1); 
                    x.y2=((response.d[i].Y2);                                       
                    jobactivityVM.arraytoadd.push(x);
                }                  

            }, //end of sucess att

            close: function (event, ui) {

                $("#divforjobactivity").dialog("destroy");
                $("#divforjobactivity").remove();
            }, // end of close 

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Unable to retrieve requested information " + errorThrown);

            }     //end of error

        }); //END OF DIALOG


       }); //end of document.ready
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is purely that you're not clearing out previous entries before adding new ones.  You should clear the `arraytoadd` array before adding new ones:

```
success: function (response) {
    //call the observableArray function with an empty array to clear it             
    jobactivityVM.arraytoadd([]);

    for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
        var x = new TemplateFunction();
        x.y1(response.d[i].Y1); 
        x.y2=((response.d[i].Y2);                                       
        jobactivityVM.arraytoadd.push(x);
    }                  
}, //end of sucess att
```

Answer (score 0):

When you close the dialog you are not clearing the jobactivityVM observableArray.  So the next time you open the dialog you make the AJAX call and add more items to the array.

Either clear the jobactivityVM when you close the dialog or reset the contents on the ajax success

```
close: function (event, ui) {
    $("#divforjobactivity").dialog("destroy");
    $("#divforjobactivity").remove();
    jobactivityVM.removeAll();
}
```

or

```
success: function (response) {
    var newItems = response.d.map( function(item) {
        var x = new TemplateFunction();
        x.y1 = item.Y1;
        x.y2 = item.Y2;
        return x;
    });
    jobactivityVM.arraytoadd( newItems );
```

I would prefer the second approach as when push is called on the observableArray then any dependencies are also updated.  In your case the DOM is refreshed ( i.e. new table row added ) each iteration of the loop.  Not so important for 2 elements, will be for 100.  Also note the use of the `map` function - IE9+.  You can still use a for loop with a single DOM updatebut the code is a bit uglier

```
success: function (response) {
    var underlyingArray = jobactivityVM.arraytoadd();
    for(var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
        var x = new TemplateFunction();
        x.y1 = response.d[i].Y1;
        x.y2 = response.d[i].Y2;
        underlyingArray.push(x);   // Add directly to the real array, Knockout won't detect the change and fire any DOM updates
    });
    // Now tell Knockout to fire any subscriptions
    jobactivityVM.arraytoadd.notifySubscribers( jobactivityVM.arraytoadd() );
```